# Drupal 7 - Display articles using taxonomy in URL?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-views, drupal-taxonomy

I'm having a hard time with this Drupal 7 question.

I have a view which lists articles. Each article has a category, which is a entity referenced taxonomy term. When I visit a URL, my taxonomy should match something in the URL. For example, if I go to news/localnews, there's a taxonomy option whose value is news/localnews.

What I'd like to do is display only articles which contain the same taxonomy term as in the URL. I have no idea how to do this and I've been working on this problem for about 5 months. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

All I really want to do is add a block (or several, on most pages) which just displays a list of articles which match the taxonomy in the URL.

Can this be done? If so, how?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In your views, on the **Advanced tab**, add new **Contextual filter**
[image]
Choose **Content: Has taxonomy term ID (with depth)**[image]

Set Depth to 1 and select **Provide default value** with Type : **Taxonomy Term ID from URL**[image]

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't work for me. I just added that to my view and it displayed nothing. I think I tried that approach before, too.